# Sharepoint UploadFile 'Specified argument was out of range of valid values'

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm trying to duplicate a file from one library to another within a Remote Event Receiver.

When reaching the `UploadFile`-function, I get the following error:

`Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: bytesToCopy`

Information about the function can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.filefolderextensions.uploadfile). It has the following signature:

```
public static Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File UploadFile (this Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder folder, string fileName, System.IO.Stream stream, bool overwriteIfExists);
```

My code is:

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    ClientResult<Stream> data = curItem.File.OpenBinaryStream();
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    if (data != null && data.Value != null)
    {

         data.Value.CopyTo(stream);
         UploadedFile = destinationList.RootFolder.UploadFile(curItem.File.Name.ToString(), stream, true);
    }
}
```

As a note: `curItem`, `destinationList` and `curItem.File` are all loaded in the context.

Edit, complete error:

```
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryImplementation(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, Int32 delay, String userAgent)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileFolderExtensions.UploadFile(Folder folder, String fileName, Stream stream, Boolean overwriteIfExists)
   at PG.SHP.SCE.QCSPAddInWeb.Services.AppEventReceiver.HandleItemCheckedIn(SPRemoteEventProperties properties) in C:\Users\OBJ_JDWR\Source\Workspaces\SharePoint\SCE\Main\Source\PG.SHP.SCE\Source\PG.SHP.SCE.QCSPAddInWeb\Services\AppEventReceiver.svc.cs:line 288
```

Line 288:
[image]

How to get rid of the error?

Comment: @Drag0nvil  
Well, yeah, that's my problem.  The error is really on that line, but I cant' find bytesToCopy anywhere on that line, or any lines around it. Added more information to the question.

Comment: @Drag0nvil Length of testfile is 8 bytes.

Comment: [Google](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/deac7cb7-c677-47b0-acdc-c56b32dfaac8/uploading-bigger-files-using-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment) says maybe you could try something like `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`.

Comment: @oerkelens as usual, Google is right... Feel free to post a quick answer with some explanation, so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Well I guess the error message does kinda make sense in that way. not what I would have expected though. Good job @oerkelens

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick google search lead me to [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/deac7cb7-c677-47b0-acdc-c56b32dfaac8/uploading-bigger-files-using-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Someone had a similar problem (although he figured it had to do with file size) and solved it by resetting the stream before sending it to SharePoint:

```
using (var stream = content)
{
    ...
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // <-- The missing statement
    ...
}
```

Hope that works for you as well :)